# Get image by task id

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, one is for storing my task by id and the other which stores image paths where the images are stored in an uploads folder.

When creating a task you can upload an image, the image table has a cell for task _id which takes the id of the task the image was uploaded with.

When I try and call the images out by the task I am looking at I don't seem to be getting y results.

See my code and images:

```
$id=$_GET['id'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM upload_data WHERE task_id=$id";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

echo $id;

echo '<pre>' . var_export($result, true) . '</pre>';
```

This is the result form a var_dump

[image]

Here is the url to prove its the correct ID

[image]

Comment: "SELECT * FROM upload_data WHERE task_id=$id" to "SELECT * FROM upload_data WHERE task_id='$id'" I'm not sure but try it. I have never written a query without '' and also check parameter before quest if (ISSET($id)) so that you can understand if issue is about query or parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$id=filter_input(INPUT_GET, &id);`// make it safer

Change your query (add quotes)

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM upload_data WHERE task_id='$id'";


if(isset($id)){ `// check this before executing query`

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM upload_data WHERE task_id=$id";
  $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
}

else
{
  echo "parameter error";
}
```